# Shorter beamer navigation bar with lots of sections

Tags: beamer, sectioning, navigation

I'm trying to create a latex beamer with 8 or 9 sections, but with this much sections the navigation bar on the top of each slides looks big and occupies quite some space. Can I shorten the navigation bar and make it smaller? The slide looks like this right now.

[image: Too many sections on top]

I would like to know if it is possible to show only 3 or 4 sections at a time, like if I were in the section 6, the navigation bar shows only section 5-7, like the figure below. Or if any other ways to make it look smarter?

[image: Less sections shown]

Also, can I hide the navigation bar on some pages, like title page and the last page with nothing but logo?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To show only 3 or 4 sections in the at a time, one need to patch some beamer internal macros. To hide the navigation bar, try `\begin{frame}[plain]`, which will also suppress footlines.